# kafka debezium connect issue

Tags: apache-kafka, debezium, cdc

I have been facing issue while connecting from debezium to msk showing me error as

```
SyncGroup failed: The coordinator is not available. Marking coordinator unknown. Sent generation was Generation{generationId=35, memberId='connect-1-012917d5-0cec-4314-accc-e9cd63e8e78a', protocol='sessioned'}
(id: 2147483646 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid due to cause: error response COORDINATOR_NOT_AVAILABLE.isDisconnected: false. Rediscovery will be attempted.
```

Comment: It would be great if you told us what versions of Kafka and Debezium you're using and provide your config files. Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.